# How to interrupt a Wait attampt of errgroup when timeout

Tags: go

I have `var g errgroup.Group` and use `g.Wait()` wait for several go routines to finish. I wonder if I can set a timeout for this wait -- when the time limit is reached, abort the wait attempt.

Specifically, I would like to achieve this with a `context.WithTimeout()`. My code is like this:

```golang
func myfunc(
    timeout time.Duration,
) error {
    ctx, cancelFunc := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)
    defer cancelFunc()
    g, _ := errgroup.WithContext(ctx)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        g.Go(func() error {
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
            return nil
        })
    }
    err := g.Wait()
    return err
}
```

However, when testing the code with timeout = 5s, I noticed the wait is not interrupted after 5s is reached.

I could imagine that the `Select` and `case` statement can be useful. However, it seems that `case g.Wait()` is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

As you have noted [`Wait`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup#Group.Wait) "blocks until all function calls from the Go method have returned". The idea here is that an error in one goroutine, or cancelled context, should lead to all goroutines stopping. Generally this is done by using the `context` to determine if they need to exit; something like the following ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/7wKA-UCM4eq)):

```
func myfunc(timeout time.Duration) error {
    ctx, cancelFunc := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)
    defer cancelFunc()
    g, ctx := errgroup.WithContext(ctx) 

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        g.Go(func() error {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return ctx.Err()
            case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
                return nil
            }
        })
    }
    err := g.Wait()
    return err
}
```

This is a contrived example; in a real situation your goroutines will often be doing IO of some kind (and just passing in `ctx` e.g. `http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, "GET",...)`).

If you cannot do this, and don't wish to wait for the goroutines to exit, then `errgroup` may not be the most appropriate tool (e.g. [this](https://go.dev/play/p/TMW1WYZa2kM) might be simpler). You could implement a workaround like ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/acq_NHOOMGp)):

```
func myfunc(timeout time.Duration) error {
    g := new(errgroup.Group)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        g.Go(func() error {
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
            return nil
        })
    }

    done := make(chan error, 1) // buffered so sending to done will not block if after timeout
    go func() {
        done <- g.Wait()
    }()
    select {
    case err := <-done:
        return err
    case <-time.After(timeout): // Warning <-time.After() is not garbage collected before expiry
        return errors.New("timeout")
    }
}
```